# What is the issue with this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, dom-events

I believe something on this code chunk is not properly coded making it incompatible on XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

The code snippet collapses div and then on click they will expand.

Can somebody see what could be wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle(div){
el = document.getElementById(div);
    if (el.style.display == 'none')
    {
        el.style.display = '';
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

</script>
```

I have this before the `<BODY>` tag. If I remove the DOCTYPE another menu I have stops working but then the rows expand by default and aren't collapsed.

Comment: Are you passing in the ID of the div and not the class?

Comment: e) Not enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with a simple display css attribute on the div. There was a markup error.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should check if passed argument is valid (e.g. not `undefined`, empty string, etc.).
2. You should check if `document.getElementById(div)` found the element (e.g. even valid name will not work while document is loading and `<script>` is earlier in the source than element you're referring to).
3. You're creating global variable `el` (put `var` in front of assignment).
4. W3C recommends Transitional DTD should be avoided whenever possible, and today it is possible not to use `<font>` and `bgcolor`. Use XHTML **Strict**, unless you don't know what a MIME type is, then use HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `el.style.display = '';` try `el.style.display = 'block';`.

Comment: that would be worse. `display=''` nicely reverts to default, which may need to be `table-row`, `inline`, etc.

Comment: @porneL - Does it revert to the default on all browsers?

Comment: Yes. Perfectly in all cases. `.style` is just convenient interface to HTML `style` attribute. It's not a actual computed style of the element, so there's no harm in removing _the override_ (just like there is no harm in removing `style` attribute from HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the `style.display = ''`, but rather set it to `'block'`, `'inline'` or `'table-row'`.